# Find minimum of various predicates

Tags: prolog, backtracking, minimum

I want to find the minimum value of all permutations called from `main` predicate. For simplicity, I have removed my entire code, assume that I just want to find the **minimum of head elements of all permutations**.

```
appendlist([], X, X).
appendlist([T|H], X, [T|L]) :- appendlist(H, X, L).

permutation([], []).
permutation([X], [X]) :-!.
permutation([T|H], X) :- permutation(H, H1), appendlist(L1, L2, H1), appendlist(L1, [T], X1), appendlist(X1, L2, X).

%min(X, A, B) X is the minimum of A, B
min(X, X, Y) :- X =< Y.
min(Y, X, Y) :- Y < X.

solve([Head|Rest], Head):-
   writeln([Head|Rest]).

main :-
   Sort = [1, 2, 3],
   PrvAns is 1000,
   permutation(Sort, X),
   solve(X, Here),
   min(Ans, Here, PrvAns),
   writeln(Ans),
   PrvAns = Ans,
   !, fail;
   true,
   writeln(PrvAns).
```

I want to calculate the minimum on fly for each permutation. Now, permute is working fine, and you can see that solve prints all permutations and even returns the first value Head properly, but `PrvAns = Ans` is wrong.

Expected output PrvAns : 1

Comment: `main() :-` is invalid syntax, FYI.

Comment: The `!, fail; true` without parentheses looks suspicious to me. The precedence of `;` tends to trip people up, I would try parenthesizing things more explicitly in `main/0`.

Comment: [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495963/find-min-of-list-using-fail-backtracking-prolog)

Comment: Does the linked question answers this too?? I'm asking because  in order to find the min without backtracking I think requires to store the permutations while in other question non-backtracking worked fine...

Comment: @coder there is another way, which is to say something along the lines of "X is the minimum of L if there is no Y in L such that Y < X." That requires `forall/2`, which is probably not what the prof intended: `min(X, List) :- member(X, List), forall(member(Y, List), X <= Y).` That uses backtracking without storing permutations, but doesn't explicitly fail.

Comment: @DanielLyons ,yes but this finds the min in one list, how could this be used for all permutations without using back tracking ??

Comment: @coder The smallest value in the list is the smallest value regardless of the permutation order. The smallest value in the head position of a permutation of a list is just more unnecessary structural windowdressing around the same question. Is this not the question you're trying to answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I didn't understand properly (and tell me, so I can help you), but, you mean something like this?

```
    findMinHead(X,Z):-
        findall( Y, ( permutation(X,[Y|_]) ), Z1 ),
        min_list(Z1,Z).
```

in this predicate we find all the Y values where Y is the head of a permutation of X, put all that values in a bag, and then find the min.